504 The request has been terminated because it has reached the maximum request timeout GCP
I have two Google Cloud Run services called 'A' that make client rest calls to another service 'B' to get information from a MongoDB database. The strange thing is that the request made https://A/revisions/463fc2ce-9140-47f7-8294-240a5640a49b/pages sometimes produces 504 errors with the message 'The request has been terminated because it has reached the maximum request timeout', however the same call but with a different revision id eg: https://A/revisions/543fc2ce-9140-47f7-8294-240a5640a49b/pages there is no problem, the first revision brings less information in the response than the second revision.
Looking at the logs of client 'B' I have been able to observe that it shows the message of type warning: Truncated response body. It usually implies that the request timed out or the application exited before the response was finished.
I have also been able to observe that there is no problem with CPU or memory and in both cases the CPU is always active.
This is the configuration that I have in the yaml in both services:
resource_requests:
cpu: 1
memory: 512
resource_limits:
cpu: 1
memory: 512
min_scale: 1
max_scale: 100
cloud_run_gen: gen2
ports:
name: http1
port: 8080
startup_cpu_boost: true
cpu_always_allocated: true

What could be happening?

If your service is processing long requests, you can increase the request timeout.
The timeout is set by default to 5 minutes (300 seconds) and can be extended up to 60 minutes (3600 seconds).
gcloud run services update [SERVICE] --timeout=[TIMEOUT]


Hello Alex Pliutau, first of all, thanks for the reply
I have a question: if instead of changing the timeout time, I change it so that the service uses http/2 instead, could it reduce the problem of: 'Truncated response body. Usually implies that the request timed out or the application exited before the response was finished.' and the 504 errors on the server side?
It is strange that this is happening for a specific revision id, the response being very similar depending on the filter

@AndresSanchez not sure about the truncated response body. Is the response big and maybe there some limitation around that?
